# ggplot object returned by function prints blank plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I created a package in R with a function that returns a ggplot object. Whenever I try to call this function to print the plot, a blank canvas is created, unless I use a workaround:

1) Add extra elements to the ggplot object when I call it in the console
2) Print it to a different window using dev.new()

I would like to be able to print the plot normally in the plot window, without these workarounds.

I've tried checking the current graphics device and turning all graphics devices off, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
> dev.cur()
RStudioGD 
        2 
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

**However, when I create a new, virtual graphics device using dev.new(), the function plots successfully to a new window.** While the window is open and I list the devices, I get the following:

```
> dev.list()
RStudioGD       png   windows 
        2         3         4
```

**Additionally, if I add a title to the ggplot it prints normally to the plot window:**

```
p <- myFunction(myArguments)
p + ggtitle("") 
## Prints to the plot window successfully
```

The following element additions also fix the issue:

```
p + y_lab("")
p + x_lab("")
p + aes("")
```

Creating any arbitrary ggplot in the console works as well.

Just to be sure, the class of the function output is correct:

```
> class(p)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

I expect the output of my ggplot object to be the appropriate plot, but it instead prints a blank canvas when entered into the console.

Comment: Just to be clear; `p <- myFunction(myArguments)` never actually shows the plot. You need to print `p`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am aware of this -- when I save the variable `p <- myFunction(myArguments)` and then try to print it by entering `p` (or just `myFunction(myArguments)`) into the console, a new plot is created in the plot window.  However, the new plot is blank.

Comment: I am getting what seems to be the same issue. Interestingly it does not create a new blank plot if an initial plot is already shown in RStudio, i.e. seems to only occur if the plot window is not initialized (`is.null(dev.list()`) is `TRUE`). There was a plot window issue with the new version of R and RStudio, I assume this may be an unintentional byproduct of these updates as well.